# Softlayer api: How to check that a VSI has been created an cancelation request on "Anniversary Date"?

Tags: python, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

For a newly created VSI, we can cancel it on "Anniversary Date".  The API billing_item.cancelItem can helps to accomplish it.  Then in the website/devicelist of softlayer, the CancelDevice button will be unable. [image]

My question is how to check that a VSI has been created an cancelation request on "Anniversary Date" or not by api ?  Ohter word, I want the api to get the status of a VSI has been submit the cancelation request or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to see the "cancelationDate" property of the vsi's billing item if the value of the property is "null" it means that the VSI has not been cancelled. In case that the VSI has been cancelled in "Anniversary Date" the value of the property will be equals to the date when the machine is going to get canceled

see the example below to get the "cancelationDate" property of a particular VSI:

```
import SoftLayer

USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

vsiId = 123

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
vsiService = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest']

objectMask = "mask[id, cancellationDate]"

try:
    result = vsiService.getBillingItem(mask=objectMask, id=vsiId)
    print(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to retrieve the VSI's billing item. " % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

list all the VSIs and their billingItems

```
import SoftLayer

USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
vsiService = client['SoftLayer_Account']

objectMask = "mask[id,hostname, billingItem[cancellationDate]]"

try:
    result = vsiService.getVirtualGuests(mask=objectMask)
    print(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to retrieve the VSI's billing item. " % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

Comment: Thank you.  My requirements are that scan soft-layer vsi list which has been create before ,and auto submit   cancelation request on “Anniversary Date” if needed.  Some time a vsi may be has already cancel by deleteObject method.  If then I call siService.getBillingItem with the deleted vsi id, the api will throw a Exception.  Soft layer api 's exception is hard to check what's type of error for is error code is Unreliable.   SO, could you tell me another api which can helps to check the vsi has been canceled or not ?

Comment: Otherwise, could you show me how to check which error happen by code when there is a exception as : [ SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): This cancellation could not be processed. Please contact support. This billing item is already canceled.].  Maybe you will offer method that use searching keywords 'already canceled' in the error message to determine the cause of the error. But I think this method is Unreliable. Any other way can help to exactly check what type of error ?

Comment: Oh, I found you have already use this [ except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to retrieve the VSI's billing item. " % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
], could you offer the e.faultCode list of softlayer ?

Comment: the error happens when the VSI has been already deleted, Intead to use the getBillingItem you could list all the VSIs in your account and use an object mask to get their billingItem and their cancellationData, if you see that that the VSI does not have an associated billingItem it means that it has already cancelled and soon the VSI is going to be removed from your account. I updated my answer.

Comment: Regarding the faultCode you need to see that on Documentation http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest some method list the errors, but others nope